# getContentPane() requiring to be cast

Tags: java, swing

I have created a class which extends JFrame, which by default will have a JPanel created with it. I have tried this:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

JPanel pane;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Main() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    int WIDTH = 500, HEIGHT = 500;
    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setTitle("Window");
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    pane = getContentPane();
}
```

I'm using Eclipse, and it's giving an error, suggesting that I cast `getContentPane()`to return a `JPanel`, but to my understanding, this is what it should be returning already. I inserted `System.out.println(getContentPane());` and it said in the console that it was returning a `JPanel`, so I'm a little confused as to why it needs to be cast. Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks.

Comment: You can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 6):

`Container` is a parent in `JPanel`'s inheritance hierarchy

`getContentPane()` returns a `Container`, which in this case, is a `JPanel` object. Therefore, a cast is required to cast the `Container` to its more specific child type, as shown below:

```
pane = (JPanel) getContentPane();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. But as JPanel is a child of Container, doesn't that automatically make JPanel a Container through inheritance?

Comment: It does, but not necessarily the other way around, so a cast is necessary. All JPanels are Containers, but not all Containers are JPanels.

Comment: Ah ok. It's weird though cause I've seen in different code snippets around the web examples where it works without being cast. Check this out for example:  [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/333338/GUI/java/BorderLayout-JLabel-size)

Answer (score 4):

If you read the [JavaDocs for `JFrame#getContentPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#getContentPane--) you will see it returns an instance of `Container`, before you can assign it to a `JPanel` variable, you must cast it

In many cases you really should test to see if the return result is actually an instance (or is assignable to) a `JPanel` using `instanceof` in an `if` statement

Comment: Thanks. In using the sysout to see the result in the console window, it indicated it was a JPanel.

Comment: So? All getContentPane tells you is its a type of Container. If you know it's another type, you'll need to cast it

Comment: This is an example of polymorphism, where, because of its inheritance chain, JPanel can act like a Container, but Container can't act like a JPanel

Comment: And a another thing, you shouldn't make assumptions about what an API "might" return, getContentPane guarantees it can return a Container, from experience, I know it tends to return a JPanel, but there's no guarantee of this, so you shouldn't be blind casting either

Answer (score 3):

> it's giving an error, suggesting that I cast getContentPane()to return a JPanel, but to my understanding, this is what it should be returning already

You get the error because you called:

```
getContentPane();
```

from a JFrame where the return type is a `Container`, and you are trying to assign a `Container` into a `JPanel`:

```
JPanel pane;
pane = getContentPane();
```

---

If you do not get the idea why the above is not allowed, think about this.

[image]

Since all Dogs are Animal, so in terms of code, you can always do this:

```
Animal animal = new Dog();  //Assign dog as Animal (O.K)
```

---

However if I have an Animal. Can I say it is definitely a Dog?

```
Dog dog= new Animal();      //Assign animal as dog (NOT O.K)
```

The answer is no, unless you specifically tell me ***"trust me, this animal is a Dog. Let me assign this Dog object to a Dog variable.".***

This idea is the same as casting in programming:

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
Dog dog = (Dog)animal;     //Tell Java this animal is indeed a Dog (O.K)
```

---

Now, your scenario of using the JPanel and Container is the same.

[image]

```
pane = getContentPane();           //Assign Container into JPanel (NOT O.K)
pane = (JPanel)getContentPane();   //Assign Container (casted as JPanel into JPanel) (O.K)
```

---

> Ah ok. It's weird though cause I've seen in different code snippets around the web examples where it works without being cast. Check this out for example

The codes from your given link works because, the code only uses a `.add()` method from `getContentPane()`.

***Note***: `getContentPane()` returns a `Container` object.

---

If you look at the [documentation of Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html), `.add()` is a method of `Container` class.

Since it is invoking a method which belongs to `Container` class. It will definitely work and no casting is needed.

Casting is needed unless you invoke a method from a subclass of the Container (such as a JPanel). For example,

```
getContentPane.add(whatever);        //Casting NOT needed, add() is a method of Container
((JPanel)getContentPane()).getUI();  //Casting needed, getUI() is a method of JPanel
```